# How to activate another addon and have it stay when default blend is called on new file command

Tags: add-on

How can my script be sure that some other script used gets loaded.

For now, I'm using 
    addon_utils.enable("some_needed_addon") 
inside the register() function of init.py of my script

and 
    addon_utils.disable("some_needed_addon") 
in the unregister()

and at the biginning or this init.py I have

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(my_first_py_file)
    importlib.reload(my_second_py_file)

else:
    import bpy
    import addon_utils # To use some other addons
```

etc.

With all that, when you call the new file command, the other script is no longer activated so it is not callable, because I didn't save it in user preferences and don't want to because I'm not sure user will want that.

Answer (score 4):

If your add-on depends on another.

You can enable it from the script like this:

```
import addon_utils
addon_utils.enable("another_addon", default_set=False, persistent=True)
```

- `default_set`: to leave the users preferences alone.
- `persistent`: to keep the add-on loaded, even when the user runs *File -> New*.

This can be called from the `register` function.